# How to show a list of task lists on a site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, classic

Have been searching the web and asked my SharePoint partner but haven't found a workable solution to what I want to achieve. I am hoping clever minds here can help me further.

Scenario:
I have a site that contains two or more task lists. I would like to have a webpart/app that shows a list of all the task lists for that site. Users can click on a task list in that list to go to it.
To complicate matters:  For each project we do, we will have such a site with an amount of task lists. So I want to save the site as a template to be able to re-use the site.

I would prefer to make use of standard webparts/apps, maybe the script editor webpart to run scripts. Is this possible?

Working on SharePoint Online with the Classic experience.

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT1:
The answer by @Zdeněk Vinduška got me on the right track. Instead *contentclass:0x0108* I had to use *contentclass:STS_List_Tasks* and enter the path to the site.

Additional question: Is it possible to use something like *this site* or *current site* instead of a full path? It would make it a lot easier to work with if I use the site as a template for other project sites.

EDIT2: Found it! (I think :-) ) If I use *path:{site.URL}* it only finds task lists on the site I am working on. Will try to create a template and do some testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello use **Search Content Query Web-Part** and as filter use `contentclass:0x0108`. It will display all Task lists.

You can also create another web part which will display all tasks for user: `contentclass:"STS_ListItem_Task" AND "path:"https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/" AND "AssignedTo:"Name Lastname"`

- You'll need to filter Path to for displaying Task Lists only from this site, so use `Path:https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/*`

[MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/building-search-queries-in-sharepoint)